Using ARA plugin support for ansible
I am using jenkins which is executing ansible commands in a linux VM.
I want do be able to use ara plugin support.
As so I know I need to add this command into my VM machine:
export ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS="$(python3 -m ara.setup.callback_plugins)"

If I manually add it when I log in through ssh it will work only in the current ssh session. So when I try to execute any ansible instructions using jenkins it will not be available (in the same or different user).
How can I make it so that I can use that export so that Jenkins will also be able to use it (and for me to use ara plugin when I lauch jobs from jenkins) ?

Add it to the Jenkins users' shell initialisation script(s), e.g. ~/.bahsrc .. I don't know how you launch Jenkins, so can't say for sure which of the options you'd have to use.

Thanks. What do you mean? I use Jenkins to launch Ansible jobs. I can tell you what you need to know for you to help me :)

Well ... if you log in directly, what do you get for id -a and ls -lad ~/.*? Add that to your question ...

Scrap the thought I had in the comments. Just record the output of python3 -m ara.setup.callback_plugins  and slap that at the end of your
callback_plugins = ./plugins/callback_plugins:/usr/share/ansible_plugins:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback_plugins

path in ansible.cfg separated by a colon : ...

This, or define the same as a global environment variable in Jenkins.

When I do echo $(python3 -m ara.setup.callback_plugins), the result is /home/xpto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ara/plugins/callback. In this case which should be my callback_plugins var?

@AlexanderPletnev if you want to set it as a global variable where should I do it? For this to be available for all users using iterative and non iterative logins (ssh)?

Here's a good guide - I'm talking about Global properties but other options might work for you as well, for example, you can set them per agent.

As I might be using another tool in future I'd prefere so do it directly into the VM itself. Anyway I could do it outside jenkins? Like in bashr or other file? for all users using iterative and non iterative logins (ssh)? @AlexanderPletnev

@H.N. - I don't know, as I don't know what you currently have in your ansible.cfg. And if you modify ansible.cfg that should work for everyone (assuming that they don't all have local installations of both ansible and jenkins - you didn't tell us anything about your setup in your question, nor did you mention multiple people).

ok, one more question, why do you have these 3 paths? ./plugins/callback_plugins:/usr/share/ansible_plugins:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback_plugins
I guess these are diferent paths for ansible to look for to callback_plugins. SO in this way I can use this cfg for multiple environments, even if they have different callback paths

One more thing, anyway I can put callback_plugins = $(python3 -m ara.setup.callback_plugins) in ansible.cfg. Instead of the hardcoded path.

No, you can't. That's a config file, not a bash-script. That wouldn't get evaluated.

I guess if I have 3 possible paths, the best way is to place them all in Ansible.cfg callback_plugins

Indeed ... which is what I suggested in the first place. :)

Absolutely True :)
